# How to check if a nodelist has an element with no content in it?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nodelist

I want my function to check if there is an element with no content in it first, then if the condition is true- execute the code, else don't run the function. I just don't know how to check whether there is an element with no content in it.

```
function randomBlock(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length)
    if(blocks[random].textContent == ""){
        blocks[random].textContent = "O"
    } else{
        randomBlock()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a recursive function?

Comment: You could also use `filter()` to make an array of just the empty elements, then pick one of them randomly.

Comment: You might want to use `blocks[random].textContent.trim()` so that elements with only whitespace are considered to have no content.

Comment: I am using this function in a tic-tac-toe game. After I click a button it adds "X" to its content, then it executes randomBlock() so it checks if the randomly selected block is empty if it is then it prints "O" if not in searches for another random number

Comment: The thing is it gives me problem when there are no more blocks

Comment: `const empties = [...document.querySelectorAll(".block")].filter(blk => !blk.classList.contains('filled'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the `NodeList` to just the empty ones, then select a random element. After filtering, you can check whether there are any empty blocks available.

```
function randomBlock() {
    let emptyBlocks = [...blocks].filter(block => block.textContent.trim() == "");
    if (emptyBlocks.length > 0) {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyBlocks.length);
        emptyBlocks[random].textContent = "O";
    } else {
        console.log("No empty blocks left");
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I write in the else statement to stop the function, I tried return but it didn't work

Comment: The function doesn't repeat. If you don't want the console.log, just remove the entire `else` statement.

Comment: If you mean you want to stop the caller, you should return something that it can check. Or you could throw an exception.

Comment: in the console it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined at randomBlock"

Comment: that's when there are no more blocks

Comment: Sorry, in JS we need to test the length explicitly.

Comment: I am new to JS and I didn't quite understand

Comment: Thanks, mate! That's my second day in Stack Overflow and I am already loving it.